Is there an alternative to "AT+CUSD=2" in nokia
I am writing a c# application which I use SerialPort and AT COMMAND, I am stuck in USSD respense and I can't cancel it because I'm using nokia 5130 as gsm modem which it doesn't have the cancel session (AT+CUSD? Only show (0,1))
The provider changes offers frequently so I don't know the results in advance and I can't change the phone either
Session timeout last for 50sec
Tried ATH, AT+CUSD =0, closings port and reopen it, AT+CUSD=2 gives error

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
